# grails populating g:select from query

Tags: list, grails, select

Trying to become a grails convert I have begun converting an existing application to Grails and Groovy. It works very well but I get stuck on the conversion of select tags.

I have a domain class:

```
package todo

  class Person {

    String ssn
    String firstname
    String familyname
    String role
    String emailname
    String emailserver
    ...
```

When creating a new "todo" task an owner may be assigned from those persons in the system who are developers and I get this working (a fairly direct translation from PHP):

```
<select id="owner" name="owner">
  <option>Noboby ...</option>
  <g:each in="${Person.list()}">
    <g:if test="${it?.role=='developer'}">
      <option value="${it?.id}">${it?.firstname} ${it?.familyname}</option>
    </g:if>
  </g:each>
</select>
```

But every attempt to make it more "Grails-ish" fails. How can it be moulded into Grails v2.2.1 code? I spent hours reading, trying, failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<g:select optionKey="id" from="${Person.findAllByRole('developer')}" optionValue="${{it.fullName}}" value="${yourDomainInstance?.person?.id}" noSelection="['null':'Nobody']"></g:select>
```

And in your class:

```
class Person {
....
String getFullName(){
   it?.firstname+' '+ it?.familyname
}

static transients = ['fullName']
....
}
```

See [g:select tag](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Tags/select.html) for more details

Comment: `optionValue="it.fullName"` will not work. You need `optionValue="${{it.fullName}}"`

Comment: Yes, you are right. And optionValue="fullName"? Note: keep it simple (=

Comment: This last suggestion was what I finally used and my solution more and more looks exactly like this one, so I check yours instead

Comment: This is super late.. but I kind of wonder if this should be done on the back end. You're doing a call to the backend from the front end where it should just be done on the back end and passed down if possible.

Comment: @DavidBrewer, that's not a call to back end from front end. g:select is relosved in server side before sending the response.

Answer (score 2):

If you woulkd like to make it more Grails style, you should perform all your logic within `controllers` \ `services` not in the view.

Assuming you have a view `createTodo` in the folder `person` and the `PersonController`, then modify your `createTodo` action like this:

```
class PersonController {
    def createTodo() {
        def developers = Person.findAllWhere(role: 'developer')
        [developers: developers, ... /* your other values */]  
    }
}
```

So you don't need to handle with database operations in your view.

Next step is to use the [g:select tag](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Tags/select.html) like this:

```
<g:select name="owner" from="${developers}" optionValue="${{'${it.firstName} ${it.familyName}'}}" noSelection="['null':'Nobody ...']" optionKey="id" value="${personInstance?.id}" />
```

Comment: Alternatively you could modify your Person class as described by Mr. Cat to simplify the optionValue part of the g:select tag.

Comment: I tested the @aiolos and @"Mr. Cat" solutions and found a number of other flaws in my first dive into Grails. However I will mix both these solutions in my final implementation. Both of you are worth some upvotes but I am not permitted to.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it working as I want to and it works (almost) according to the @"Mr. Cat" solution. One little detail, though, 'it' does not exist in the class so the getFullName method had to become:

```
String getFullName(){
   this?.firstname+' '+ this?.familyname
}
```

Up and working, thank you for all help.